# Why tfidf of one document is not zero?

Tags: nlp, tfidf

I'm new to nlp. Recently I wanted to do little nlp tasks, and faced strange thing.
That is I have run the following code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

docs = ["strange event"]
tfIdf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', tokenizer=word_tokenize,
                                   stop_words=stopwords, ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=True,
                                   norm='l2')
tfidf = tfIdf_vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)
print(tfidf)
```

and see the following result

```
  (0, 2)    0.5773502691896258
  (0, 0)    0.5773502691896258
  (0, 1)    0.5773502691896258
```

shouldn't the tfidf of one single document be zero? (Since the IDF=log(1/1)=0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because, by default sklearn's TF-IDF vectorizer will normalize the results. See the the [Tf-IDF Term Weighting](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting) section of the User Guide. For your example,

```
n = 1
tf = 3
df = 1
idf = np.log(n/df)+1 = 1
```

You have 3 terms with identical frequency. So, the L2 normalized tf-idf is computed as

```
abs(1)/sqrt(1+1+1) = 0.577
```